# Biztalk error X2065 when adding fault message to port

Tags: xml, port, biztalk, fault, biztalk-orchestrations

I'm trying to handle faults from an API in my orchestration.

I created a schema that looks like the xml-fault I get from the API, then I added a Fault Message to the operation for the port using that schema.

The idea is to have a send port subscribe to fultmessages and save them to a folder.

But when I try to compile my BizTalk orchestration I get an error:
"error X2065: the 'response' messagetype must have a 'body' part distinct from any 'fault' messagetype 'body' part"

Googling this error I get nothing, so right now I'm stumped.

[image: BizTalkPort]

Response xml:

```
<response>
  <result>
    <case_number>case_number_0</case_number>
    <table_sys_id>table_sys_id_0</table_sys_id>
    <table_name>table_name_0</table_name>
    <status>status_0</status>
  </result>
</response>
```

Fault xml:

```
<response>
  <error>
    <detail>detail_0</detail>
    <message>message_0</message>
  </error>
  <status>status_0</status>
</response>
```

Is it possible to solve this or should I make a schema that holds both structures and then pick it apart in the orchestration? I can not change the responses from the API, it is what it is.

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: I used your workaround, I catch SOAP Exceptions and handle them. If we get a System exception those are catched in another catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically telling you that your root element or namespace must be different on the error response.

Is the API you are calling actually sending back a non 200 series HTTP error?  If not then it will simply come back on the response part of the logical port, and you just need a XPath expression to see if it is a error or a result, or have a map that creates a payload that adds counts of those nodes, and have a If shape based on that.

If the API is actually giving a 400 or 500 series error, it will throw it as a SOAP error, and that is the schema you need (which is available out of the box)

Note: There is a know bug with the WCF-WebHttp adapater (or at least on some version of BizTalk, I'm going to verify if this still exists in BizTalk 2020)

Details from my blog [BizTalk 2013 R2 known bugs, issues & quirks](https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/biztalk-2013-r2-known-bugs-issues-quirks/)

> BUG: BIZTALK WCF-WEBHTTP ADAPTER DOES NOT SET THE MESSAGE TYPE ON ERROR

> Details: When you get a non 200 series http status code from a RESTful service using the WCF-WebHttp adapter, the SOAP fault message published to the message box does not have the context property MessageType.  This means you cannot map it or catch it in a Fault on the Logical Port in the Orchestration

> Work around: Catch it in a System.Exception block in the Orchestration, see (BizTalk 2013 R2 JSON Encoder error – “[Object reference not set to an instance of an object” – Part 1)](https://connectedpawns.wordpress.com/2015/11/26/biztalk-2013-r2-json-encoder-cannot-process-soap-faults-part-1/) or use BRE rules in a Pipeline to handle the SOAP Exception see BizTalk 2013 R2 JSON Encoder error – “[Object reference not set to an instance of an object” – Part 2](https://connectedpawns.wordpress.com/2015/11/29/biztalk-2013-r2-json-encoder-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-part-2/)